# GAS getSheetByName exits process when name does not exist

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following line of code works when the name is found but just exits the process when the name does not exist:

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name);`

Has anyone run into the same issue? Is there another way to check if a sheet exists prior to calling that function maybe? I did not find any.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a `try{  }` to catch and handle the error

Comment: What do you mean by "just exits the process"? Add a [mcve] to clarify this. Note: `getSheetByName` returns null if there isn't a sheet with the specified name

Comment: @Rubén in V8 if the sheet does not exist the error bar is not shown, it appears as if the script just finished.

`var name = 'sheet';
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name);`

Answer (score 0):

It was just a debugger fluke. I actually had a bug in the calling function when displaying an error dialog when the sheet was not found. The process would just exit with no error message when tracing over that line so it was odd.